# How to run Jasmine JS in ReSharper?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, resharper

I started out with a .NET 4.5 solution in VS2015, with the latest ReSharper plugin. I followed this tutorial:

https://blogs.endjin.com/2014/09/unit-testing-angularjs-with-visual-studio-resharper-and-teamcity/

All I get is `Inconclusive: Test not run` in ReSharper's Unit Test Sessions window.

When following this tutorial:

https://evanhahn.com/how-do-i-jasmine/

I can run the test page in a browser and the two tests fail, correctly.

What I don't understand is why ReSharper would not be running the tests when I have the same references in the `serviceSpec.js` file as in the `SpecRunner.html` file.

I would also like to know how I can get some more information out of ReSharper about the problem it sees in attempting to run my tests.

Here is my servicesSpec.js:

```
///<reference path="~/bower_components/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js"/>
///<reference path="~/bower_components/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine-html.js"/>
///<reference path="~/bower_components/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/boot.js"/>
///<reference path="~/bower_components/angular/angular.js"/>
///<reference path="~/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js"/>

describe("Testum",
    function() {
        describe("Service test",
            function() {
                it('should at least run this test',
                    function() {
                        console.log("stuff");
                        expect([1, 2, 3].length).toBe(3);
                    });
            });
    });
```

Here is the SpecRunner.html which passes (I simplified the tests) in a browser window:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Jasmine Spec Runner</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../bower_components/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.css">
    <script src="../../bower_components/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js"></script>
    <script src="../../bower_components/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine-html.js"></script>
    <script src="../../bower_components/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/boot.js"></script>
    <!-- include source files here... -->
    <!-- include spec files here... -->
    <script src="shared/orderServiceSpecs.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In the Resharper settings, what version of Jasmine have you selected? Also there is a bug in Resharper 2016.2 which prevents Jasmine from working so update to 2016.3

Comment: I have Jasmine latest set in the options and ReSharper is on the latest version.

Comment: Try switching to Jasmine 2.5.2 or so, and disable all other testing frameworks in Resharper settings.